# why the data segment (ds) is 0 ? even the other legal variable(integer) is there

Tags: c, linux, null

I wrote the following C program.

```
int main() {
  int i = 3;
  char *q = "hello";
  char *p = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile and debug it with gdb, I get the following reg information..

```
gcc main.c -g
gdb a.out

info reg:
cs  0x33   51
ss  0x2b   43
ds  0x0    0
```

My question is if `ds` is 0, how integer `i` and `char* q` are getting their physical address?

Comment: Is this on a 64-bit machine? x86-64 ignores most segmentation, so ds is allowed to be 0.

Comment: And on Linux `i` and `q` don't really have physical addresses (at the application level), but only *virtual addresses*. Read more about processes and address spaces, e.g. in http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is compiler dependent.A data segment is a portion of virtual address space of a program, which contains the global variables and static variables that are initialized by the programmer.Global and statically allocated data that initialized to zero by default are kept in what is called the BSS area of the process.The heap is where dynamic memory (obtained by malloc(), calloc(), realloc() and new – C++) comes from. . A stack segments is where local (automatic) variables are allocated. So i ,p and q are stored in stack segment.A code segment contains compiled program. RO (read only) segment contains constant string like "Hello"

Answer (score 1):

Here i and q are a part of stack of the main function. After compilation, they boil down to addresses on the stack. So, they won't be a a part of the data segment.